# QT - Can I dynamically point to GUI's labels using a variable passed into a method?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm creating an inventory and want to reference my inventory Forms QLabels with the name of the item passed into my method.

The QLabels and the names of the items are the same so I wanted to reduce if statements by referencing a QLabel depending on the name of the item passed in.

```
void Zork::on_btnTake_clicked()
{
Item *item = new Item(ui->takeItem->currentText().toStdString());  
Colin->addItemToInventory(item);
inventory_screen->addItem(item->getDescription());  //Enables the Item in the Inventory
currentRoom->deleteItem(item);
ui->takeItem->removeItem(ui->takeItem->currentIndex()); //Only remove the item in the foreground of combobox at the time take button was clicked

}
```

Calls this Method addItemToInventory(item):

`void Inventory_Ui:: addItem(string itemName){
      myUi->itemName->setText(QString::fromStdString(itemName));
}`

I am unable to do so as itemName is not a member of Ui, although itemName does contain members of Ui.

**Example:**

In my Inventory_Ui Form I have 6 labels, one named broken_bottle.  I want to pass broken_bottle into the method's parameter itemName and them use that as a reference so at run-time it would look like `myUi->broken_bottle->setText`...

Answer (score 0):

I think I follow what you are asking to do.  I would access it with `findChild` or `findChildren`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren

```
QList <QLabel *> labels = ui->myForm()->findChildren<QLabel*>();

QLabel* targetLabel = 0;
foreach(QLabel * label, labels)
{
    if(label->text() == ui->takeItem->currentText())
    {
        targetLabel = label;
        break;
    }
}

if(targetLabel != 0)
{
    // ... do something with targetLabel

}
```

or...

```
QList <QLabel *> labels = ui->myForm()->findChildren<QLabel*>();

foreach(QLabel * label, labels)
    label->setObjectName(label->text());

// later

QLabel * targetLabel = ui->myForm()->findChild<QLabel*>("text of label");

if(targetLabel)
    // use it
```

Or if you are connecting all these labels to the same slot, you can figure some of it out using the sender static method.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender

```
void MainWindow::on_takeItem_currentTextChanged()
{
    QLabel* targetLabel = qobject_cast<QLabel*>QObject::sender();

    if(targetLabel)
        // do something with it
}
```

Hope that helps.